# When does part 1 end?

Tags: nier

I was googling for missable quests in *Nier* and found out that the game is split into two parts. I won't be able to finish quests from part 1 after starting part 2.

Could someone give me a spoiler-free hint about when the first part ends so that I'll know when I really have to finish all quests? One site said something about "entering the manor" - I didn't read further because of spoilers - so I suppose they meant part 2 begins when I've got to enter the manor between Seafront and Nier's hometown?

Answer (score 4):

You're right: once you enter The Haunted Manor, which lies between your hometown and Seafront, the second part of the game begins. Make sure to finish all side quests before talking to the butler outside of the manor.