# Why can't I give Yonah a pumpkin?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

I am trying to complete the *Yonah’s Gift* sidequest in Nier Replicant 1.22. I've harvested a pumpkin like Yonah asked, but when I try to give it to her she just apologizes for coughing all the time. I know I'm about to hit a point-of-no-return, so I want to complete this before advancing the story.

Why can't I give Yonah a pumpkin? How do I complete *Yonah's Gift* before the point of no return?

Comment: Related: [*When does part 1 end?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/104215/181240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As Wondercricket mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/389530/181240), the quests *Yonah's Cooking* and *Yonah's Gift* are uncompletable once you finish the mansion. However, if you play on PC and don't mind cheating a little, you can use [a save file editor](https://acurisu.github.io/NieR-Replicant-ver.1.22474487139/) to mark the quests as completed.

1. Go to https://acurisu.github.io/NieR-Replicant-ver.1.22474487139/
2. Click the arrow icon to open the file selector.
3. Open `Documents\My Games\NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139\Steam\<steam_id>` and select the `GAMEDATA` file.
4. Select the save slot you want to edit.
5. Open the 'Quests' section.
6. Add *Yonah's Cooking* and *Yonah's Gift* to the sections 'Available' and 'Completed'.
7. Click the save icon to download your modified save, then overwrite your original save.

Comment: Too bad this is a PC only trick :(

Comment: @Wondercricket Unfortunately yes, this only works on PC. Just edited that into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I give Yonah a pumpkin?

This happened to me as well. Since you have reached the part right before the point-of-no-return, then unfortunately you can no longer complete this side quest. This quest (as well as *Yonah's Cooking*) must be completed shortly before the point of no return. Since the quest is not completed, it should appear under the "Incomplete Quests" section in your quest logs.

Story/lore wise, during this part of the story, you should have learned or at least will about to learn that

> Yonah's condition has worsen, and you are tasked with finding medicine for her. Since she is extremely sick, she does not have the energy to take part in the events of those quests.

> How do I complete Yonah's Gift before the point of no return?

At this point, the only way to complete this side quest is to replay through Part 1 - which only be done by starting a brand new game or make your way through the story and unlock the requirements needed for Route E.

> Route E also requires you to start a new save file, but branches off into a secondary storyline that follows Kaine

Comment: Is it possible to get 100% quest completion during Route E?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I haven't gone through Route E myself, so I do not have an answer to that question. Sorry!